# how to access a variable in a dictionary?

Tags: python

I have  a variable Ginfo as below,am trying to access Url using GInfo[GerritInfo['Url']] but running into an error...can anyone point how to access Url?

```
Ginfo  = {'Assignee': smritig, 'RCAInfo': 'Provided', 'PLProductLine': 'APSS.LA.0.0', 'GerritInfo': [{'Url': 'https://review-android.quicinc.com/506928', 'Status': 'MERGED', 'Info': 'Available'}], 'CRId': '<a href="http://prism/CR/436931">436931</a>', 'CRStatus': Fix, 'RNotesStatus': 'Yes', 'TargetName': NA, 'IsDevComplete': ''}
```

Comment: Your edit makes no sense.  Now there is no context.

Comment: `type({''})` is `<class 'set'>`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Matthias He edited the question and that edit took away all the necessary information.

Comment: Ah, I see (or better: I don't see). The question is meaningless now.

Answer (score 5):

You should access it like this

```
GInfo["GerritInfo"][0]["Url"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python dictionary declaration:

```
dictionary = {"key1":value1", "key2":"value2"...}
```

Now to access a certain value inside that dictionary, let's say value1, you go like this:

```
dictionary["key1"]
```

The code above will give you value1.

```
dictionary["key2"]
```

And this code will give you value2

Comment: Ah, Thank you, Kobi. It seems you edited my answer. I am not accustomed to stackoverflow and did not quite know how